# MPLAB X project directory file colors - what do they mean

Tags: microchip, mplab

I'm resurrecting a project from a decade ago. The previous programmer was old school and did everything via the command line. By all accounts his code is very well written. I'd like to move this to MPLABX with support for the processor that we're using PIC18F6628 and PICkit4 debugger. I've added all the files shown in the attached project directory. I get many compile errors and suspect that I'm not including the correct header/source files. I notice the the directory structure shows the file names with different colors and suspect that this is trying to tell me something. Can anyone tell me what the different colored files mean?

Thank you for your help

[MPLAB X - Current View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfX9X.png)

I've tried to add the source and header files back in one at a time. I've checked the directory location of the referenced files. It's not clear to me what the problems is here.

Comment: This don't look like compile errors. Whats's the result of the compiler?

Comment: Hi Mike - The compiler output is a mess. So many errors that the compiler bails out. Among other things, the compiler suggests that "int" is unrecognized. This is why I'm checking the included files to be sure that they are correctly configured - thus making me wonder why the file names in the project have different colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project is under version control. Blue: File has been edited compared to last commit. Green, file is the same as in last commit.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I presume that grey means that the file is missing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).